# Changing GTK theme for Scilab 6.0g

Tags: java, gtk, scilab, manjaro

I can't for the life of me figure out how to change the GTK theme for Scilab in Manjaro Deepin. It runs this darker theme by default, but it doesn't change all the colors and the fonts are pretty bad.

It doesn't seem to be related to the _JAVA_OPTIONS variable that's set up (as it only lists openjdk). There's also no mention of 'theme' anywhere in the scilab executable file. Switching themes in the gtk-theme switcher doesn't seem to have any effect. Running it as root also doesn't change anything. Adding "GTK_THEME=deepin-dark" to the shortcut also has no effect. Just to be pretty thorough, no, Scilab settings doesn't seem to cover any sort of theme customization (just console colors).

Help please?

[Theme switcher set on deepin-dark theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Ldf.png)

[No separators, fonts and random white parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w49Q4.png)

Comment: [Andrea Sosso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15214263) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66209631) saying "Visit "Scilab font problems" in the ArchLinx fourm: [link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1954094#p1954094)"